# Is the variance of these two variables the same?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, random-variables, symmetry

Let  $X$ and $Y$ be random variables having joint density function
$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
 x + y & \text{for } 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1 \\
 0 & \text{other }x, 0 \leq y \leq 1
\end{cases} $$

In this case, I claim that the $Var(x) = Var(y)$ because the density function is symmetric. Is my claim correct?

Note: I am not looking for somebody to tell me how to find $Var(x)$. I do realize that:
$$ Var(x) = \mathbb{E}\left[x^2\right] - (\mathbb{E}[x])^2 $$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: (1) you likely mean a more general second condition on the pdf and (2) if so, the problem is symmetric in $x,y$ so indeed the variances (and any other characteristics) would be identical...

Comment: @gt6989b If you could post your comment as an answer I could accept it and close the question.

Comment: @Bob posted - please take a look. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You likely mean a more general second condition on the pdf and
2. if so, the problem is symmetric in $x,y$ so indeed the variances (and any other characteristics) would be identical.